# Segmentation fault when using ctypes and threading

Tags: python, c, multithreading, segmentation-fault, ctypes

I wrote a Python wrapper for a C library using `ctypes`. Everything worked fine, until I tried it with the `threading` module.

Here is a small example to reproduce it:

## foo.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

char *foo_init() {
    char *result = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    assert(result);
    return result;
}

char foo_get(const char* p) {
    return *p;
}

void foo_set(char *p, char value) {
    *p = value;
}

void foo_del(char *p) {
    free(p);
}
```

## foo.py

```
import threading
import ctypes
libfoo=ctypes.CDLL('foo.so')

libfoo.foo_init.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
libfoo.foo_get.restype = ctypes.c_char

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__obj__ = libfoo.foo_init()

    def get(self):
        return libfoo.foo_get(self.__obj__)

    def set(self, value):
        libfoo.foo_set(self.__obj__, ctypes.c_char(value))

    def __del__(self):
        libfoo.foo_del(self.__obj__)

x = Foo()
x.set(b'x')
print(x.get())

def compute():
    y = Foo()
    y.set(b'y')
    print(y.get())

t = threading.Thread(target=compute)
t.start()
t.join()
```

Compilation:

```
gcc -Wall -shared -o foo.so -fPIC foo.c
```

Execution:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
python3 foo.py
```

Result:

```
b'x'
[1]    8627 segmentation fault  python3 foo.py
```

We see here that `x.get()` is correctly printed whereas `y.get()` does a segmentation fault. Thus, it seems that there is a problem linked to `ctypes` and `threading`.

Note that if I move the initialization of `y` outside of the `compute` function, then the program exits normally.

Moreover, each of the functions which manipulate the pointer produce a segmentation fault (e.g. if I just keep the `__init__` and `__del__` functions, there is still a crash).

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: You set the wrong return types, and you didn't set any argument types. Fix those and see if the result behaves differently.

Comment: What return type should I use? I tried c_char_p, but then I have the error *** Error in `python3': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fd25ec0da28 ***

According to the documentation, c_char_p is for NUL terminaded char*, which is not the case here.

Comment: Quoting the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_char_p), "For a general character pointer that may also point to binary data, `POINTER(c_char)` must be used.".

Comment: Thanks a lot, it fixed my problem. I posted an answer with the code modification to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user2357112 gave me the answer in comments: adding the (good) return type and the arguments types is important.

Replacing the beginning of `foo.py` by the following fix the problem:

```
libfoo.foo_init.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char)
libfoo.foo_init.argtypes = []
libfoo.foo_get.restype = ctypes.c_char
libfoo.foo_get.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char)]
libfoo.foo_set.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char), ctypes.c_char]
libfoo.foo_del.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char)]
```